# How to extract only the n-nth HTML title tag in a sequence in Python with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a Wikipedia table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Most_Valuable_Player_Award) about the MVP winners over NBA history.

This is my code:

```
wik_req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Most_Valuable_Player_Award")
wik_webpage = wik_req.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(wik_webpage, "html.parser")

my_table = soup('table', {"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders sortable"})[0].find_all('a')
print(my_table)

for x in my_table:
  test = x.get("title")
  print(test)
```

However, this code prints all HTML title tags of the table as in the following (short version):

```
'1955–56 NBA season
Bob Pettit
Power Forward (basketball)
United States
St. Louis Hawks
1956–57 NBA season
Bob Cousy
Point guard
Boston Celtics'
```

Eventually, I want to create a pandas dataframe in which I store all the season years in a column, all the player years in a column, and so on and so forth. What code does the trick to only print one of the HTML tag titles (e.g. only the NBA season years)? I can then store those into a column to set up my dataframe and do the same with player, position, nationality and team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need for that dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Most_Valuable_Player_Award"
df=pd.read_html(url)[5]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
     Season                  Player  ...    Nationality                       Team
0   1955–56             Bob Pettit*  ...  United States            St. Louis Hawks
1   1956–57              Bob Cousy*  ...  United States             Boston Celtics
2   1957–58           Bill Russell*  ...  United States         Boston Celtics (2)
3   1958–59         Bob Pettit* (2)  ...  United States        St. Louis Hawks (2)
4   1959–60       Wilt Chamberlain*  ...  United States      Philadelphia Warriors
..      ...                     ...  ...            ...                        ...
59  2014–15          Stephen Curry^  ...  United States  Golden State Warriors (2)
60  2015–16      Stephen Curry^ (2)  ...  United States  Golden State Warriors (3)
61  2016–17      Russell Westbrook^  ...  United States  Oklahoma City Thunder (2)
62  2017–18           James Harden^  ...  United States        Houston Rockets (4)
63  2018–19  Giannis Antetokounmpo^  ...         Greece        Milwaukee Bucks (4)
[64 rows x 5 columns]
```

If you **really** want to stick with BeautifulSoup, here's an example to get you started:

```
my_table = soup('table', {"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders sortable"})[0]

season_col=[]
for row in my_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    season = row.findChildren(recursive=False)[0]
    season_col.append(season.text.strip())
```

I expect there may be some differences between columns, but as you indicated you want to get familiar with BeautifulSoup, that's for you to explore :)

Comment: Thanks, that certainly helps. However, I'm trying to get familiar with BeautifulSoup so it would be great if I knew how to handle it there as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Added an example if you want to play with BeautifulSoup and get the individual columns.